# using your keyboard to light up a box using javascript

Tags: javascript

How do you make a specific Key make a box/selection on your screen light up when being pressed? eg if i press M i want the middle box to light up

Comment: `window.addEventListener("keypress", function (e) { /* check e.keyCode, do stuff */  });`

Comment: so i have a grid and i want box 5 to light up.

Comment: if this is my HTML</head>
<body>



<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item1">1</div>
  <div class="item2">2</div>
  <div class="item3">3</div>  
  <div class="item4">4</div>
  <div class="item5">5</div>
  <div class="item6">6</div>
  <div class="item7">7</div>
  <div class="item8">8</div>
  <div class="item9">9</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: what do i need to write in javascript to make it light up? sorry im new to this whole process and would just like clarification

Comment: You will need some script here libby. I would use a keyCode class name to map.

Comment: ok so Chris G
i just want to know what you mean by { /*check e.keyCode, do stuff*/}

Comment: See below libby.

Comment: Sorry, I know you're new and stuff, but you're supposed to know at least the basics before posting here. This isn't a how-to site or free coding school.

Answer (score 1):

Here we go, we list for key down and look for item implementing the class and add highlight. (NOTE: Use querySelectorAll and forEach if you want multiple)

```js
const findDiv = (key) => {
  let className = `.key${key}`; 
  return document.querySelector(className);
};

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  let div = findDiv(e.key);
  if(div) div.classList.add('highlight');
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach(d => d.classList.remove('highlight'));
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item keyShift">1</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowDown">2</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowUp">3</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowLeft">4</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowRight">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Omg Thank you so much for helping me, really appreciate it helping me learn new hard techniques

Comment: No problem, happy coding.

Comment: I don't think `class = "item keyShift"` will work. With "Shift", we need to specify `class = "item keyShiftLeft keyShiftRight"`

Comment: It does work. Try it :). Libby here is a full list of key names. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values

Comment: @Cat remember this is only demo, I am sure libby has her own keys in mind. The list will help her choose.

Comment: Oh, that's great. I bet I was thinking of `event.code` instead of `event.key`